# How do i search for multiple column values in a php table that have the same OTHER column values?

Tags: mysql, search

I have mysql tables on my computer for some of my movies. One table is info about cast (movieID#, castID#, charName).

Example

#movieCast table

```
MOVIEID                :  idNum      :     charName

The Black Velvet Gown  :  Bob Peck   :     Miller

The Black Velvet Gown  : Janet McTeer  :  Riah Millican
```

Is there a way to search the database using a single search so that I can search for movies that have both actors? Such that both HAVE to be in the movie. Or do i have to create an array for the 1st actors results, an array for the 2nd actors results, and compare them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this schema:

```
create table movieCast (
  movieID varchar(255),
  castID varchar(255),
  charID varchar(255)
);

insert into movieCast (movieID, castID, charID) values (
  'The Black Velvet Gown',
  'Bob Peck',
  'Miller'
);

insert into movieCast (movieID, castID, charID) values (
  'The Black Velvet Gown',
  'Janet McTeer',
  'Riah Millican'
);

insert into movieCast (movieID, castID, charID) values (
  'Just Bob',
  'Bob Peck',
  'Himself'
);
```

You can use a query like this to get movies with both Bob and Janet (notice the movie "Just Bob" who stars only Bob Peck does not show up in results):

```
select movieID from movieCast
where castID in ('Bob Peck', 'Janet McTeer')
group by movieID
having count(*) = 2;
```

The key is to change the `having count(*) = 2` to however many actors you place in the `where castID in ('Bob Peck', 'Janet McTeer')`

You can view this fiddle to see it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/722025/7/0

Answer (score -1):

Just use `IN` in your search.

```
SELECT * FROM movieCast
WHERE charName IN ('Riah Millican', 'Miller') AND 
movieID = 'The Black Velvet Gown';
```

Your english is not good, so I am just guessing what your question is. :)